# Question regarding complex partial derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis

I have completely understood that you can write a complex function $f:G\to \mathbb{C}$ where $G\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is open, as $f=u+iv$ where $u=\Re(f)$ and $v=\Im(f)$ are real valued functions of two variables on G. In that case it is relevant to talk about partial derivatives for $u$ and $v$.

What I however do not understand, is how it it possible to talk about the partial derivates of the complex function $f$ itself, as we are only dealing with one variable z in that case?

The reason I'm asking it because I'm currently dealing with harmonic functions and I can't understand how you can talk about a complex function being harmonic because we usually view complex differentiability in the one variable approach i.e. the difference quotient $\frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{h}$ approaches $f'(z_0)$ for $h\to 0$

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, and if I am reading you correctly, the answer lies in the chain rule.

Define
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+ \frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)
$$

And complex differentiation becomes more about partial differentiation of $u, v$ wrt $x+iy$ than differentiation wrt $z$.

Comment: I have trouble understanding this. What is the purpose of defining this?

Answer (score 0):

Every analytic complex function of the form $f(x,y)=u+iv$ can be write as $f(z)$, this is because $2x=z+\bar{z}$ and $2iy=z-\bar{z}$. Indeed we can say for every analytic function $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}=0$. Then we can deal with a function of one variable $z$ in this case, like a real function (in most cases), one of you want is chain rule.

In general case, one may write a harmonic function with the form of
$$f(x,y)=f(z,\bar{z})$$
here we are dealing with a function of two variables $z$ and $\bar{z}$. You can talk about the partial derivatives like real case or other properties (of course in most cases).